# elastic search does not obey mapping when update adds a new field

Tags: python, templates, dynamic, elasticsearch, updates

Using python update API I add a string field to my ES indexed documents.
Even my mapping has this:

```
"mappings" : {
    "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                { "notanalyzed": {
                      "match":              "*", 
                      "match_mapping_type": "string",
                      "mapping": {
                          "type":        "string",
                          "index":       "not_analyzed"
                      }
                   }
                }
              ]
    },
```

the newly added field is still analyzed. Anybody noticed the same problem?

Here a piece of python code that adds the new column:

`res = es.search(index=ind, body=st, size=2000)
 for rec in res['hits']['hits']:
     es.update(index=rec['_index'],doc_type=rec['_type'],id=rec['_id'], body={"doc": {"srcSite": sS}})`

So the newly added "srcSite" is still somehow "analyzed". I have tried to add the new field explicitly into the template but that did not help either.

Comment: How does your relevant python code look like? Also please share a sample document and the effective mapping for your string field.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found what was the problem. It appears that the template somehow gets fixed at the time a document was created and changing the template later will change nothing - even if one updates the document it won't use the changed template but an original one...